# How to prove something is NOT a ring isomorphism?

Tags: universal-algebra, ring-homomorphism, ring-isomorphism

I have a question about rings (I assume ring without the requirement of multiplicative identity element).

Suppose, I want to show, for two rings, there is NO ring isomorphism (the rings are not isomorphic).

Let´s take an arbitrary homomorphism $h$. I think every ring isomorphism has to map zero to zero. So is it sufficient to show that there exist two elements $a,b$ such that $f(a + b) = 0$, but $f(a) + f(b)$ cannot be zero?

(The "+" on the left and right side are the additive operations of the two corresponding ring, they dont have to be defined the same btw).

Is my thinking correct?

Thank you.

Comment: You have not assumed that $a+b=0,$ so how does a fact about $f(a+b)$ get you anywhere in deriving $f(0) \neq 0$ for your desired contradiction. If you *do* assume $a+b=0$ then why introduce $a,b$ at all, just show $f(0)\neq 0$ directly.

Comment: @coffeemath If I dont assume a + b = 0, but f(a +b) = 0 and f(a) + f(b) isnt zero, isnt it enough for the proof? I dont understand why not. Because then the f cannot be isomorphism.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes that is enough. [I was not thinking it out enough.]

Comment: @coffeemath Okay. And do you think if f(a + b) is 0 and f(c + d) is also 0, then the isomorphism rules are also violated? (In other words, do we need injectivity for the f?)

Comment: Injectivity definitely not needed. A map sending everything to $0$ of target ring is a homomorphism, though a very trivial one.